# OpenGL create cylinder help in towers of hanoi

Tags: c++, opengl, towers-of-hanoi

Hi I am trying to create a Towers of Hanoi OpenGL application. I am using the glut extension to make the window and glu to create the cylinder. The problem I am having is that the cylinder is drawn similar to a ring but I want it stand vertically can some one explain to me why my cylinder is drawn that way and point me in the way of how i can fix it?

```
#include <gl/glut.h>

GLfloat pos[] = { -2, 4, 5, 1 }, amb[] = { .3, .3, .3, 1 };
GLfloat front_amb_diff[] = { .7, .5, .1, 1 };
GLfloat back_amb_diff[] = { .4, .7, .1, 1 };
GLfloat spe[] = { .25, .25, .25, 1 };

void display(void){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    //trying to create cylinder here
    glPushMatrix();
    GLUquadricObj *qobj = gluNewQuadric();
    qobj = gluNewQuadric();
    gluQuadricDrawStyle(qobj, GLU_FILL);
    gluCylinder(qobj, .1, .3, 2, 40, 40);
    glRotated(90, 1, 0,0 );
    glPopMatrix();

        //create first torus
        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslated(1.5, 0, 0);    
        glRotated(90, 1, 0, 0);
        glutSolidTorus(.1, .3, 100, 100);
        glPopMatrix();

        //create more next to it
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++){
            glPushMatrix();
            glTranslated(1.5, 0, 0);
            glTranslated(i/-1, 0, 0);
            //glRotated(theta, axes[axis][0], axes[axis][1], axes[axis][2]);
            glRotated(90, 1, 0, 0);
            glutSolidTorus(.1, .3, 100, 100);
            glPopMatrix();
        }

    glutSwapBuffers();

}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
    glutInitWindowPosition(200, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("GLUT");
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-2,2,-2,2, 2, 8);

    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, front_amb_diff);
    glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, back_amb_diff);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, spe);
    glMaterialf(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, 75);

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, amb);

    glLightModeli(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_TWO_SIDE, GL_TRUE);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslated(0, 0, -5);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, pos);

    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);


    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: torus is not cylinder use [gluCylinder](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluCylinder.xml) instead. if you want to make a hole then you need to do the mesh yourself ...

Comment: glRotated only affects draw calls after the call. So when you want to rotate the cylinder, you should call glRotated first and then gluCylinder.